# Reflections laser - algorithmic task

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have the following task:

**Laser:**

On a plane arranged sequentially numbered very thin, double-sided mirror. At one point issued from the laser beam - Your task is to see which of the mirrors will be reflecting beam.

**Entrance:**

In the first row there are 4 floating-point numbers `lx`, `ly`, `dx`, `dy` defining sequence coordinates of the point from which came the laser beam and the direction in which follow. The next line is the number of mirrors `n`. In the following `n` lines there are 4 floating-point numbers `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` specifying the appropriate coordinates of the beginning and end of the mirror. Numbering starts from the mirror 1.

**Exit:**

The numbers of mirrors, of which subsequently bounced off the beam. Tests are chosen so that the beam always reflects from a finite number of mirrors.

---

**Example:**

> In:
>
> 1 1 1 0
>
>  3
>
>  4.5 0.5 5.5 1.5
>
>  4 4 6 5
>
>  5.5 2.5 4.5 3.5

‍‍‍‍‍‍

> Out:
>
> 1 3

---

**Picture with way:**

[image: Picture with way]

---

I tried to determine the perpendicular lines, and solved equations but it does not help. Can someone help me and guide me to the solution?

Comment: "... but it does not help" why not? what is the problem? Please show the code

Comment: Here is my code http://pastebin.com/SuyUa6sv . Unfortunately, his idea of action is bad. It is based on finding the point symmetrical to the perpendicular line passing through the point for the solution of the equation describing the laser and stretch

Comment: Search for "intersection of ray and line segment"; that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

So thin thing is built upon a line-segment / ray test. There are several ways of performing this, but the easiest is to translate the start point of the segment to 0,0 (subtract all your points but not dx, dy). Then rotate the system so that dy = 1.0. Then check if lx is on the segment 0 to the translated and rotated x2.

You then need to move back into your real co-ordinate space, and create a new ray, with lx, ly at the intersection point and dx, dy reflected along the normal to the mirror (rotate the normal so that ny is 1 and rotate dx, dy with it, flip the sign of dy, and rotate back). Then you go for another iteration, until all your intersection test fail and the ray shoots off to infinity.